# JPA returning empty result list while DB returns row set

Tags: java, sqlite, jsf, jpa, jpql

I am trying to run a query to fetch some statistic data from my database. And I'm using `JPA`. But I faced such a trouble: when I run `JPQL` query, the empty result set is returned. But when I run `SQL`, produced with `JPA` for that `JPQL` query, I got a single row of data.

Here's what I've got:

**The Ticket entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tickets")
public class Ticket extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    private Owner owner;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="flightId")
    private Flight flight;

    private String status;

    public Ticket() {
        this.status = "AVAILABLE";
    }
```

**The Flight entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="flights")
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String departure;
    private String destination;
    private Date date;
    private float ticketCost;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="flight", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
```

**The result row class**

```
public class SoldReportRow {
    private String departure;
    private String destination;
    private DateTime date;
    private int ticketsSold;
    private float totalCost;

    public SoldReportRow(Date date, String departure, String destination, Long ticketsSold, Double totalCost) {
        this.departure = departure;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.ticketsSold = ticketsSold.intValue();
        this.totalCost = totalCost.floatValue();
        this.date = new DateTime(date);
    }
```

**The JPQL**

```
SELECT NEW entities.SoldReportRow(f.date, f.departure, f.destination, 
    COUNT(t.id), SUM(f.ticketCost)) 
FROM  Ticket t JOIN t.flight f  
WHERE t.status = 'SOLD' AND t.owner IS NOT NULL AND f.date BETWEEN ? and ? 
GROUP BY f.id
```

**The generated SQL**

```
SELECT t0.DATE, t0.DEPARTURE, t0.DESTINATION, COUNT(t1.ID), SUM(t0.TICKETCOST) 
FROM flights t0, tickets t1 
WHERE ((((t1.STATUS = ?) AND NOT ((((((t1.ADDRESS IS NULL) 
    AND (t1.EMAIL IS NULL)) AND (t1.NAME IS NULL)) AND (t1.OWNERFROM IS NULL)) 
    AND (t1.PHONE IS NULL)))) AND (t0.DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?)) 
    AND (t0.ID = t1.flightId)) GROUP BY t0.ID
```

So here is what I got when I run `JPQL`:

[image: JPQL gives an empty results' collection]

And here is what I got when I run the generated `SQL`:

[image: SQL gives a single row]

**UPD: the TicketDAO methods**

```
// ...

protected static EntityManagerFactory factory;
protected static EntityManager em;

static {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(UNIT_NAME);
}

// ...

public static List<SoldReportRow> soldReportByDate(String from, String to) {
    DateTimeFormatter dfTxt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter dfSql = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    String startDate = dfSql.print(dfTxt.parseDateTime(from));
    String endDate = dfSql.print(dfTxt.parseDateTime(to));

    String query = String.format(
            "SELECT NEW entities.SoldReportRow(f.date, f.departure, f.destination, COUNT(t.id), SUM(f.ticketCost)) FROM " +
            "Ticket t JOIN t.flight f " +
            "WHERE t.status = 'SOLD' AND t.owner IS NOT NULL AND f.date BETWEEN '%s' and '%s' " +
            "GROUP BY f.id",
            startDate, endDate
    );

    return TicketDAO.query(SoldReportRow.class, query);
}

public static <T> List<T> query(Class<T> entityClass, String query) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<T> q = entityManager.createQuery(query, entityClass);
    List<T> entities = null;

    try {
        entities = q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    return entities;
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return factory.createEntityManager();
}
```

**The question is**, why does this happen and how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem obviously comes from your query. Show whats inside the method `TicketDAO.soldReportBy`

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan here you go! =)

Comment: Print the parameters's values before (or just after) passing them into the method , and lets us know what you have there already. No `null` reference, right ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan dates are correct and are `sprintf`-ed right into a query. So the trouble is not there i think...

Comment: Print out the String `query`, you will see clearer. The problem might not come from there though. Did you try the getSingleResult method ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan `SELECT NEW entities.SoldReportRow(f.date, f.departure, f.destination, COUNT(t.id), SUM(f.ticketCost)) FROM Ticket t JOIN t.flight f WHERE t.status = 'SOLD' AND t.owner IS NOT NULL AND f.date BETWEEN '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-30' GROUP BY f.id` is the query string

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan `[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-04-09 02:11:25.068--ServerSession(1326241430)--Connection(781388466)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--SELECT t0.DATE, t0.DEPARTURE, t0.DESTINATION, COUNT(t1.ID), SUM(t0.TICKETCOST) FROM flights t0, tickets t1 WHERE ((((t1.STATUS = ?) AND NOT ((((((t1.ADDRESS IS NULL) AND (t1.EMAIL IS NULL)) AND (t1.NAME IS NULL)) AND (t1.OWNERFROM IS NULL)) AND (t1.PHONE IS NULL)))) AND (t0.DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?)) AND (t0.ID = t1.flightId)) GROUP BY t0.ID
 bind => [SOLD, 2014-04-01, 2014-04-30]
` is the SQLite log

Comment: Use getSingleResult method if you are expecting a single row.

Comment: The idea is that i am expecting a set of row ;)

Comment: In this case, a catch statement would certainly be useful in your try block.

Comment: But nothing is catched nor thrown

Comment: Seems that the issue is caused by using the `BETWEEN` operator with dates. Dates are passed in correct format, althought select returns nothing...

Comment: But you said the SQL returned a row value in the database console, therefore `BETWEEN` can't be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

After the research, I've found that the trouble was caused by the data at the database. By default, SQLite does not have the `DATE` column type. And it uses strings to describe timestamps. So for date comparison (just like `SELECT ... WHERE date BETWEEN a AND b`) it's better to use UTC date form, not string one (`1397036688` is the better value than the `2014-03-09`).

Comment: Glad you found the problem. I never used SQLite, but  guess it's good to know that there is no DATE column type by default in that DBMS. And yes its easier/faster to sort/compare numbers than a set of characters, so its better :)